# Perl virtual environments?

Tags: perl, solaris-10

### Background (not a mandatory read)

I started my current job as a web development intern. The guy who was teaching me left half way through and I have basically been left up sh*t creek with only a Google paddle since there is almost no documentation on how to run any of the servers. Instead of developing, I now mainly maintain the software on the servers including the company Intranet.

### Situation

Im used to working with Python, but we currently have a Development Intranet which is down and seems to run on, or at least is started by, Perl scripts. The server is running Solaris 10.

Im trying to run a .pl file but the system complains that it cannot find `LWP/Simple.pm`

`LWP/Simple.pm` is there, but its under a different Perl version.

**perl/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/LWP/Simple.pm**

But the current version is:

`@INC`:

```
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib
/usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4
/usr/perl5/site_perl
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4
/usr/perl5/vendor_perl
```

**bash-3.00# perl -V**

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 4)

I am very reluctant to install anything new, as this MUST have been started before, so everything should be in place. I just need to understand how all of this works. Is `@INC` like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

How would you switch the current version? Is there something for Perl which is like `virtualenv`?

I've had a go at declaring the Perl version, but that just gives the same error message:

```
perl/bin/perl5.6.1 bin/emwd.pl
```

The actual error is:

`Can't locate LWP/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /ade_autofs/ade/perl/bin/Solaris/Opt/lib/5.6.1/sun4-solaris /ade_autofs/ade/perl/bin/Solaris/Opt/lib/5.6.1 /ade_autofs/ade/perl/bin/Solaris/Opt/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/sun4-solaris /ade_autofs/ade/perl/bin/Solaris/Opt/lib/site_perl/5.6.1 /ade_autofs/ade/perl/bin/Solaris/Opt/lib/site_perl .) at bin/emwd.pl line 173.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bin/emwd.pl line 173.`

Seems straight forward, but Im not sure I should be changing `@INC`

Comment: There may be multiple versions of Perl installed. Check the install directory for binaries containing version numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Two likely things here:

1) is there a perl in a different path?  Maybe it's run by hand from there.

2) your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` equivalent is `PERL5LIB`.  Check around and see if there's anything setting that.

after you get that figured out, time to start carving yourself a better paddle :)  There are lots of options including building a complete library tree under a path and then using `PERL5ENV` on that, or even building your own standalone perl+libraries and invoking that in all your scripts.

Oh yeah - Solaris!  I suspect it's running not-your-system-perl.  Check for `/opt/csw/bin/perl` or similar.  We do that on our one Solaris host - call the csw perl for stuff we want to run, and leave the system perl alone.

Answer (score 1):

> How would you switch the current version? Is there something for Perl which is like virtualenv?

Yes, [Perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) is a virtualenv equivalent for Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use perlbrew, as pointed by [starfish](https://serverfault.com/users/68739/starfish), and run the script in the new enviroment.

You can also install `LWP::Simple` in a local dir, say `/home/falcon`, and add the this line to the top of your script `use lib '/home/falcon';` [(as answered here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)